# Why didn't Jack answer Leonard's question?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

Officers Jack and Exley visit Leonard in *L.A Confidential* (1997), who is working out on a speed bag. They ask for
his help in identifying suspects. Leonard agrees when Jack offers to reduce his brother’s
sentence. Leonard provides information about Sugar Ray Collins, who drives a maroon '49 coupe
and enjoys killing dogs. Jack thanks Leonard and notes the location is nearby:

> Leonard: **So I'll hear from you, right?
> About my brother?**
>
> Jack: Keep it up, Lenny. Up.
>
> *Then Jack and Exley get in the car and leave*.

Here Jack did not directly answer Leonard's question. Instead, he responded with the
phrase "Keep it up, Lenny. Up."

Why didn't Jack answer Leonard's question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the script:

> JACK
>
> You got a brother up in Folsom.  I
> know because I put him there.
>
> BOXER
>
> Till 19-fucking-70.
>
> JACK
>
> How'd you like to make it 1960?  I
> know the judge and Sergeant Exley
> here is friends with the D.A.
>
> Exley nods, this is true.  The Boxer's still listening.

(The last exchange between Jack and Leonard is not in the script)

Jack seems to be lying to Leonard, and Exley, who's position is true, in a way, does not correct him. They have not been through procedure, and are highly unlikely to be able to carry out Jack's claims, but Leonard does not know this, nor does he know the characters of these two policemen.

So, Jack changes the subject and makes a hasty exit.

As soon as they realize how close the address is, their demeanour changes, they've forgotten Leonard, and his brother, already, in a flash. Leonard is nothing to them now.

They know that when Leonard realizes they lied to get information, he would come after them with his boxing fists, or at least is just going to be very angry. What's the point of sticking around for that? They have their lead, time to go.